# How to use java Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

if I override my run function as ,

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            doSomePrcocess() // is the isInerrupted() flag seeting to true?
                            return; //Terminates the current Thread
                        }
                        //otherwise 
                        runScript();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
```

and then If I call, `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` from any point in the code, should the thread halt there and start running doSomeProcess() at that point? if yes, then how the interrupted flag gets to set true? If no, how to do this?

Comment: `t.interrupt()`?

Comment: yes @MadProgrammer

Comment: Although not illegal, and sometimes necessary (to re-assert the interrupted flag), you usually want to interrupt *another* thread, not your own thread. So you often need `otherThread.interrupt();` rather than `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`

Answer (score 2):

- If thread is in sleeping or waiting state calling the interrupt() method on the thread, breaks out the sleeping or waiting state

> throwing InterruptedException

- If the thread is not in the sleeping or waiting state, calling the
  interrupt() method performs normal behaviour and doesn't interrupt the thread but sets the interrupt flag to true.

Thread class has provision to deal with thread interruption as

```
public void interrupt()
public static boolean interrupted()
public boolean isInterrupted()
```

If you intend to go with the only once execution of doSomePrcocess then you have to go with which will check and clear the Thread interruption state for successive calls.

```
public static boolean interrupted()
```

Using below will only check the status and no modification.

```
public boolean isInterrupted()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got a running example with comments in your code below. Try running it a few times to see if it clarifies your concept.

Normally you would interrupt a thread from another thread and yes doSomeProcess will get invoked in the next cycle of the loop which could be 1 ms after the thread was interrupted or 1 hour after depending on the logic implemented in your methods.

```
public class InterruptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {

                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            doSomePrcocess(); // is the isInerrupted() flag seeting to true? - Yes
                            return; // Terminates the current Thread - yes
                        }
                        // otherwise
                        runScript();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void runScript() {
                System.out.println("runScript interrupted status:" + this.isInterrupted());
                sleepy(100);


            }

            private void doSomePrcocess() {
                System.out.println("doSomePrcocess interrupted status:" + this.isInterrupted());
                sleepy(500);
            }

            private void sleepy(int millis) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(millis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // try commenting this out to see what happens.
                }
            }
        };
        t.start(); 

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        t.interrupt(); // generally you would call interrupt on another thread.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work like that. The `isInterrupted` method checks if the flag is set, it does not declare a handler. There is no way to define a central handler that will automatically be called when a thread is interrupted. What you can do is to catch `InterruptedException` and call the handler, plus check the interrupt flag regularly to see if it is time to stop.

Comment: If you want to stop a thread, interrupt it.  That's why all the methods that block throw InterruptedException when interrupted, so that your thread can exit.  Basically you want to propagate the exception all the way to the top, where you catch it and then just exit.

Comment: And in general you can't stop a thread (the stop method is deprecated). You can interrupt a thread and if it cooperates it will stop, but it may just as well keep going. Having said that the right thing to do when a thread is interrupted is normally to cleanup and stop.